# Adding a method to an Xcode 10 Core Data generated file

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This question probably has an answer elsewhere, but I've only found answers for outdated versions of Xcode or projects that use Swift.

I am using Xcode 10 and reading *iOS Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, 4th Edition*. I am using such an old version because this is the resource that my work provided to me.

Currently I am trying to add a method to a CoreData generated class for Objective-C.

With CodeGen set to Category/Extension with my entity selected in CoreData the generated class files are:

- `BNRItem+CoreDataProperties.h/m`
- `BNRItem+CoreDataClass.h/m`

`BNRItem+CoreDataClass.h` includes `BNRItem+CoreDataProperties.h`, and `BNRItem+CoreDataProperties.h` includes `BNRItem.h` (which does not exist). I assume that I need to create `BNRItem.h` but I don't know what file to import into `BNRItem.h` since either `BNRItem+CoreDataProperties.h` or `BNRItem+CoreDataClass.h` would seem to create a circular include cycle.

In which file do I add an instance method to a CoreData generated class for Objective-C in Xcode 10?

Answer (score 0):

The `#import` statement was introduced to resolve the cyclic dependencies created by `#include`.
So it doesn’t matter much if you are using `#import`, but if you’re still concerned you can also use `@class` forward declaration

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to use `@class` in the `.h` file and `#import` in the `.m` file, except when `#import` is necessary in the `.h` file.  The latter occurs when referring to a superclass or protocol.

The idea is to speed up recompiles.  If `ClassA.h` imports `ClassB.m`, and you change only `ClassB.m` during development, then because `ClassA.m` imports `ClassA.h` which imports `ClassB.m`, `ClassA.m` will need to be recompiled during the next build, even though it is unchanged.

Of course, all of this goes away in Swift :)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not the actual answer, but I fixed this by changing the CodeGen to Manual/None and editing the files that it generated.

Answer (score 0):

What about leaving the code generation option to `Class Definition` and create an extension (a category in Objective-C) of your entity?

Answer (score 0):

This has always been my struggle, but just now I ran into [this Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/generating_code?language=objc).

The second way, is the way you are trying to use. The unexpected step is to move the properties file to the trash. And actually it seems the `<class>+CoreDataClass` files have to be renamed to just `<class>.h` and `.m`. After that you can use those files to extend your class and the property files keep being generated.

So the steps to create your managed object class are:

- Choose Category/Extension in the data model inspector for your entity.
- Generate your class with the `Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass...` menu.
- Move the created `<class>+CoreDataProperties.h` and `.m` files.
- Additional step: rename the data class files as just described.